# __all__ += [name for name in dir(_C) NameError: name '_C' is not defined pytorch

Tags: pytorch, torch

I'm making an application where I use torch, but when I run the file importing torch it always gives this error:

**all** += [name for name in dir(_C)
NameError: name '_C' is not defined

does anyone know how to solve?

what i know _C is a folder inside of torch folder

Answer (score 0):

Could you trying `import torch` in an empty directory?

If this works, then it is possible there are some **common names** in your application that could interfere with PyTorch.

See: [this PyTorch Discussion thread](https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/nameerror-name-c-is-not-defined-while-importing-torch/124721/2?u=noobmldude)